# Issues with querying on cassandra-driver Node JS

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I am trying to set up a connector for cassandra. When i try to query the database, it doesnt give back anything. here is the snippet

```
function CassandraConnector(host, hostPort, user, password) {
    if (!host || !hostPort) {
        logger.fatal("CassandraConnector cannot initialize without host and port configuration.");
        throw new Error("CassandraConnector unable to start");
    }
    this._dbHost = host;
    this._dbPort = hostPort;
    this._user = user;
    this._password = password;

    var authProvider = new cassandra.auth.PlainTextAuthProvider(this._user, this._password);
    client = new cassandra.Client({
            contactPoints: [this._dbHost],
            authProvider: authProvider,
            protocolOptions: {
                port: this._dbPort
            },
            keyspace: "test"       
    });
client.connect(function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error while connecting to cassandra " + err)
    }
});
client.on('log', function(level, className, message, furtherInfo) {
  console.log('Cassandra log event: %s -- %s', level, message);
})
}


CassandraConnector.prototype.getAllUserPreferences = function(user_type, userId) {
    var query = "SELECT * from test.user where user_type=? AND user_id=?";
    var params = [user_type, userId];
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    client.execute(query, params, {
        prepare: true
    }, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
            throw new Error("Unable to retrieve the user preferences for user id " + userId);
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(result)
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I put a breakpoint on deferred.reject and deferred.resolve but it doesnt hit there at all. Please help.

Comment: Simplify your code until you can determine where is the issue..., start with the [driver basic usage guide](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver#basic-usage) and go from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it to work. I had one question. When i do Select user_id from user, i get back results but when i do select * from user, i dont get back any rows. Do i always need to specify the column names?

Comment: You can do `SELECT *`, you don't have to specify the column names, you should be getting different results because of a different reason

Comment: I tried to do var query = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_type=? AND user_id=?' and pass in params but the result.rows is undefined. err object is null. When i specify the column names, the rows are returned. Any ideas?